# Open source solutions to plot and visualize Mysql data

Tags: mysql, charts, reporting

I have been searching for solutions to plot,analyse and list the data in my MYSQL tables.
While I can write SQL queries and fetch any data needed,my end users are not technical enough to write SQL queries.Are there any apps around that allow users to create charts and reports for the data in MYSQL database by just dragging and dropping? [This](http://ubiq.co/) does just that but is unfortunately a paid app.

Comment: By pure drag and drop (from the query creation to the report generation) it's higly unlikely, but as you found out, there are some paid solutions that let you do that, if you want to use open source, i'm afraind you will need to create this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a BI tool.Browse through this [PENTAHO BI TOOL](http://community.pentaho.com). Its a community edition tool. You can create many kinds of charts, dashboards.